# Как выровнять слева текст по центру по высоте?

Tags: css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Код:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
    <p>
      <span style="text-transform: uppercase;">Нейминг </span>
      <br /><br /> DEFT [ Дэфт ] — в переводе с английского означает «искусный», при этом имеет стремительное, прямое и четкое звучание, отражая смелый характер бренда и бескомпромиссное качество.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
    <img src="/images/project/honmil/5.jpg" style="width: 100%;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Работает вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как выровнять слева текст по центру по высоте?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите вертикально отцентрировать текст внутри контейнера с чёрным фоном, то добавьте элементу-родителю **div** свойство *display* со значением *flex*, а также добавьте свойство *align-items* со значением *center*, чего можно добиться добавлением бутстраповских классов [*d-flex и align-items-center*](https://bootstrap-4.ru/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#align-items), как и указал [entithat](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/272305/entithat).

[Прилагаю ссылки на русском](https://bootstrap-4.ru/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 d-flex align-items-center">
    <p>
      <span style="text-transform: uppercase;">Нейминг </span>
      <br /><br /> DEFT [ Дэфт ] — в переводе с английского означает «искусный», при этом имеет стремительное, прямое и четкое звучание, отражая смелый характер бренда и бескомпромиссное качество.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-delivering-a-parcel-dog-and-cat-1366470764.jpg" style="width: 100%;" />
  </div>
</div>
```